# Custom Ajax helper does not hit the controller in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I found a nice [exemple](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/creating_a_custom_ajax_helper) of Ajax helper for search textbox, which look like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Textbox(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, string name, 
    AjaxOptions ajaxOptions, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var tag = new TagBuilder("input");
    tag.MergeAttribute("name", name);
    tag.MergeAttribute("type", "text");

    tag.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    tag.MergeAttributes((ajaxOptions ?? new AjaxOptions()).ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes());

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Starting from this exemple I am trying to make a custom "AjaxButton", and till now I have this helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString AjaxButton(this AjaxHelper ajaxHelper, int jobId, bool apply)
{
    var myAjaxOptions = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        Url = "JobCardView/UserApply"+jobId,
        HttpMethod = "post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "userInfo",
        OnSuccess = "CallBackCardView"
    };

    var tag = new TagBuilder("button");

    var color = apply ? "warning" : "primary";

    tag.MergeAttribute("class", "btn btn-"+color);
    tag.MergeAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");

    var text = apply ? "Not Interested" : "Interested";

    tag.SetInnerText(text);


    tag.MergeAttributes((myAjaxOptions).ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes());

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

which render the following Html:

```
    <button 
class="btn btn-warning" 
data-ajax="true" 
data-ajax-method="post" 
data-ajax-mode="replace" 
data-ajax-success="CallBackCardView" 
data-ajax-update="#userInfo" 
data-ajax-url="JobCardView/UserApply2" 
data-dismiss="modal">
Not Interested
</button>
```

How can I provide the Url, inside this helper in order to run as expected?

I have `Ajax.ActionLink` which has the same options and is running ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of hardcoding your url (and forgetting to append `/` in front of the `jobId` parameter):

```
Url = "JobCardView/UserApply"+jobId
```

Try using the built into the framework tools to deal with urls (`UrlHelper`):

```
Url = new UrlHelper(ajaxHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext).Action("UserApply", "JobCardView", jobId)
```

so that you get a correct url:

```
data-ajax-url="JobCardView/UserApply/2"
```

Comment: thank you, I made the correction but still not going to the controller

Comment: Can you see the AJAX request being made in the `Network` tab of the developer console? Also what HTTP verb is being used for it?

Comment: Did you include the required client side libraries as script tags into your project? Remember that you need to include the unobtrusive ajax scripts. They will make sense of all those custom `data-*` attributes and know how to perform the AJAX request,

Comment: I use HttpPost for the action

Comment: thank you, the scripts were missing, now is working.